# How can I show a menu on both sides of the logo in Opencart 3 using Twig?

Tags: twig, opencart-3

Good afternoon, I want to put the finished layout on opencart, now I'm making a menu.
I have opencart version 3.0.3.8., because the menu is unusual, I don’t know how to implement it.
Look at the menu screen and the code that I have and tell me how to implement this menu.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQdtG.png)

header.twig file code

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__list">
  {{ menu }}
    <li class="nav__item">
     {% if logo %}
       <a href="{{ home }}" class="nav__link nav__link--logo logo">
          <img src="{{ logo }}" title="{{ name }}" alt="{{ name }}" class="logo__img" width="128"           height="104" />
       </a>{% else %}
     {% endif %}
   </li>
 </ul> 
</nav>
```

menu.twig

```
{% if categories %}
  {% for category in categories %}
          <li class="nav__item">
             <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="nav__link">{{ category.name }}   </a>
          </li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I tried to implement as above, but it does not work in this way to display the menu on both sides of the logo.Tell me how you can implement a dynamic menu on both sides of the logo?